# install protocol buffer compiler error under Mac

Tags: installation, protocol-buffers

I installed the protobuf complier following:
Download Protocol Buffers full source from here: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/downloads/list
Extract it and go to the extraction directory from terminal
1.Run ./configure
2.Run make
3.Run sudo make install

After I run make, the error shows. someone know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!!

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
Making all in .

Making all in src

/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++ -D_THREAD_SAFE  -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Woverloaded-virtual -Wno-sign-compare -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -D_THREAD_SAFE   -o protoc main.o  libprotobuf.la libprotoc.la -lz

libtool: link: cannot find the library `2/src/libprotobuf.la' or unhandled argument`2/src/libprotobuf.la'

make[2]: *** [protoc] Error 1

make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

make: *** [all] Error 2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm seeing this too - and I diagnosed the problem.  It's simple enough - the download directory path contains a space character.  Simply move or rename the download directory so it no longer contains a space character and everything works.

Please see my bug report [here.](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/issues/detail?id=632&thanks=632&ts=1398094715)

Comment: Please mark my comment as comment/vote it up, then!!

Comment: +1 I had this issue when building with a build server and not when building in my local dir. Sure enough, the build path on the build server had a space in it